# How to include local Boost in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

for distribution purpose, I extracted only asio lib from boost.
So that users can directly clone my git branch, and build it.

But although I set boost path to my local path (under project), log still shows that the boost I use is installed in system path.

**log: boost installed in system**

> -- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.80.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.80.0") found components: system
> Boost found at: /usr/local/include

Please teach me how to modify my cmake, thanks!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)
project(GHCtest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(BOOST_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost/include)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${BOOST_ROOT})

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found. Please set BOOST_ROOT to the Boost installation path.")
else()
    message("Boost found at: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ ${BOOST_ROOT})
add_subdirectory(src)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(GHCtest ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(GHCtest PRIVATE srclib pthread)
```

Comment: Use `find_package` with `CONFIGS` or `HINTS`. `BOOST_ROOT` is not used by `find_package` and `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost/include` is not a valid prefix path, it should be smth that ends in `cmake/Boost-1.xx.y/`.

Comment: Also make sure you've cleaned your cmake cache.

Comment: If all you want is asio you might be better off with the non-boost version https://think-async.com/Asio/

Comment: ok, I use standalone asio finally. But I still want to know how to add/extract particular lib from boost to my project. (or you recommend always cp all of the boost lib to your project folder) thanks!

Comment: @273K: Actually, `BOOST_ROOT` is used by `find_package(Boost)`. but only since CMake 3.27: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html. Because OP code has `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)`, that remark doesn't apply to it even if it is run under CMake 3.27, but in that case CMake will emit a developer note or so.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend distributing boost at all, let the user provide their own version, use the system version or use a package manager like vcpkg or conan

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here

1.

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
```

`find_package` will always look for the system level directories unless you configure it globally (which I would recommend against)

2.

```
    message("Boost found at: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

`${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is a variable that is initialized by `find-package`. So yes, `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` will return the system level directory.

3.

```
set(BOOST_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost/include)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${BOOST_ROOT})
...
...
...
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ ${BOOST_ROOT})
```

This suggests to me that you are correctly including your local copy of Boost.

So, I'm assuming that your log message was generated by `find_package` which as I mentioned earlier will always point to the system-level directory.

Try removing the `find_package` command from your `CMakeLists.txt` file and see if your code still compiles. I would expect it to compile because it seems to me that you aren't actually making use of the system-level Boost.